# passing webmethod parameter to another web method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

how can we call one web method in another web method using ajax from the first web method i need to call another web method and pass the parameters from the first to second method

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function GetCityNameArray() {
        var cities = ['Mumbai', 'Delhi', 'Chennai'];
        PageMethods.GetCityNameArray(cities, OnSuccessGetCityNameArray);
    }
    function OnSuccessGetCityNameArray(response) {
        for (var i in response) {
            alert(response[i]);
        }
    }
</script>

  <form id="form1" runat="server">

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods = "true">
</asp:ScriptManager>

    <div>

<input type = "button" onclick = "GetCityNameArray()" value = "Get City Name Array" />

    </div>
    </form>

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string[] GetCityNameArray(string[] cities)
        {
            return cities;
        }
```

Comment: i think you meant to write `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`

Comment: Just check first if the button click really happening. Put a console.log(obj) inside the button click, before the ajax call and see what you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### first Create Controller

```
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Web;
     using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace DemoApp.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
          public ActionResult Index()
           {
              return View();
            }

           public JsonResult Check(string name, string age)
           {
             string[] abc = { name, age };
             return Json(abc);
           }

         }
       }
```

### then create Your view

```
    @{
      ViewBag.Title = "Index";
     }
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20130526/json2.min.js">  </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function GetData() {

         var name = txtName.value;
         var age = txtAge.value;
     jQuery.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: '@Url.Action("Check", "Home")',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ name: name, age: age }),
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Name=" + data[0] + " And " + "Age=" + data[1]);
        }
    });
    return false;
   }



    </script>
   Name :<input id="txtName" type="text" />
   Age : <input id="txtAge" type="text" />
   <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="button" onclick="return GetData();" />
```

Comment: I think there is issue in url and you should check url

Comment: I have checked your code onclick it goes to ajax request but It wont find your url method SendParameters

Comment: Yes it is expected behavior but still issue is '  url: CS.aspx/SendParameters",'

Comment: if it is mvc I may help you but in ASP.net you must provide link like that            http://localhost/form.aspx?param1=career&param2=ride like query string

Comment: Yes definately you can

Comment: Now check my Answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116581/discussion-between-nikhil-ghuse-and-kavitha-vemula).

Answer (score 0):

When you click, does it actually fires the click function? Did you debug it? If not, first try to put a breakpoint in the first line inside the click function or add a simple alert("click works"), maybe your selector is wrong.

Comment: click is working but it is not routing to that respective method

Answer (score 0):

Also we can write the following solution in controller and fill the EmployeeDto in view side pass to controller.

```
using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Web;
     using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace DemoApp.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
          public ActionResult Index()
           {
              return View();
            }

           public JsonResult Check(EmployeeDto EmployeeDto)
           {
             string[] abc = { EmployeeDto.name, EmployeeDto.age };
             return Json(abc);
           }

         }
       }
```

Answer (score -1):

There can be a few corrections first of all you need document.ready event or another helper function (i changed to a helper function due to asp.net's clientid thing) and then you have to stop button posting back your page.

```
script type="text/javascript">
    var onSubmitClick = function() {
            var button = this;
            var obj = {};
            obj.name = $.trim($("[id*=txtName]").val());
            obj.age = $.trim($("[id*=txtAge]").val());
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "CS.aspx/SendParameters",
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    alert(r.d);
                }
            });
            return false;
    };
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td>
        Name:
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text = "" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Age:
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server" Text = ""/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClientClick="return onSubmitClick();" UseSubmitBehaviour="false" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string SendParameters(string name, int age)
        {
            return string.Format("Name: {0}{2}Age: {1}", name, age, Environment.NewLine);
        }
```